# How to delete multiple properties from an Object using a single delete?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object:

```
var myArr = {one:'1',two:'2',three:'3',four:'4',five:'5'};
```

I want to delete three properties from that object at once like:

```
delete myArr[one, three, five];
```

and it is failing. Do I have to perform an independent delete for each property like so:

```
delete myArr[one]; delete myArr[three]; delete myArr[five];
```

Thank you.

Comment: correct me if I'am wrong but myArr is not an array!!

Comment: I have said that its an array object

Comment: it's an object. There's no such thing as an "array object" in JavaScript. And yes, the `delete` statement can delete only one property at a time.

Comment: the question should be reworded with *Delete multiple properties using a single delete*.

Comment: Thank Pointy. For the purposes of distinguishing the two types of arrays in Javascript, i use 'array object' for object literal var arr={} and 'array' for anything var arr=[]. Thank you again!

Comment: @Nina: rather than commenting - and you are absolutely right - you could have simply edited the question. (Incidentally, while I've edited the question and changed the title, I've left the code mostly alone so there's a *very* badly named variable in there now.)

Comment: @DavidThomas, it was more or less a hint to the op, and my english is obviously not as good as it should be for being a lector for questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @David Thomas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an array for the keys and iterate for deleting.

```js
var object = { one: '1', two: '2', three: '3', four: '4', five: '5' };

['one', 'three', 'five'].forEach(function (k) {
    delete object[k];
});

console.log(object);
```

With [`Reflect.deleteProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty)

```js
var object = { one: '1', two: '2', three: '3', four: '4', five: '5' };

['one', 'three', 'five'].forEach(Reflect.deleteProperty.bind(null, object));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: although i like a variation of this answer like: for (var i = 0, a= obj.length; i < a; i++) {  delete obj[i]);}, i must declare you 'javascript offensive'. Sleek things this class comes from sleek minds. Thanks a million!