# remove property on object if its' key is present on array that contains keys?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of keys that can be present as propert on object, if present, I want to remove those properties on it, I know removing a single prop on object like this:

```
  const { 'removedPropOnObj', ...newObj } = obj;
```

newObj here becomes new object with removed property of removedPropOnObj, i want to do something like that but i have in this case is array of keys like:

```
['removeKey1','removeKey2','removeKey3']
```

Help?

Comment: You want to remove all the properties of object present in array?

Comment: @MaheerAli yes, that's what i want to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One liner to delete multiple object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617129/one-liner-to-delete-multiple-object-properties) and [How to delete multiple properties from an Object using a single delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806247)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `Object.keys` and `reduce()`

```js
let rmKeys =['removeKey1','removeKey2','removeKey3']
let obj = {
    removeKey1:1,
    removeKey2:2,
    removeKey3:3,
    removeKey4:4,
    removeKey5:5
}
let newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((ac,a) => !rmKeys.includes(a) ?({...ac,[a]:obj[a]}) : ac,{})
console.log(newObj);
```